# Opscenter 6.0 connect agents on the wrong IP

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I try to upgrade my datastax setup to DSE 5.01 + opscenter6.0 but I ran into an issue.

I have two interfaces per node : rpc_ip (for clients and management) and listen_ip (inter-node traffic). when I added nodes to opsc I gave the rpc_ip and it works.

opsc itself in connected to rpc_ip only.

but now opsc try to connect to listen_ip to connect agent which is not working (agent are connected to rpc_ip).

I tried both to install agent from package or let opsc install them with the same result.

Regards,

Fred

Answer (score 2):

ok, I found it :-)

in /var/lib/datastax-agent/conf/address.yaml the variable stomp_interface was not set on the correct IP. once fixed (with IP address of opsc in "rpc" network), the agent connected opsc and gave it the right IP (I presume).

in opsc node change to state 'agent detected but is unreachable via http' for a few seconds and then switch to 'agent are healty' state.

Best regards,

Fred